# Array datasort declaration API in C#

Tags: c#, z3, z3py

Given that I have custom defined data type (let's say Customer) I want to define the following array data type:

`Customers[]`.

Looking at the Z3 C# API: http://z3prover.github.io/api/html/class_microsoft_1_1_z3_1_1_context.html

`var customerArraySort = context.MkArraySort(<domain>, <range>);`

1. What does `<domain>` and `<range>` mean?
2. Would the following create a Customer[] array sort?

`var customerArraySort  = context.MkArraySort(customerSort, context.IntSort);`

Comment: What? You didn't explain your goal?

Comment: @johnny5 updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

(Disclaimer: I have no experience with Z3 or background in theorem-proving)

`Context.MkArraySort` is documented here: http://z3prover.github.io/api/html/class_microsoft_1_1_z3_1_1_context.html#ac25b9e8235bb453b4fd33de33d15e917

There are two overloads with identically named parameters, except one accepts a single `Sort domain` argument, the other accepts a `Sort[] domain` array argument.

Both methods are factory-methods for `ArraySort` class objects which represent the sorting of an array.

- `domain` and `range` are terms in mathematics that refer to the input and output of a function respectively: https://www.wolframalpha.com/examples/mathematics/mathematical-functions/domain-and-range/

(I accept that the documentation for Z3 is lacking, for example the method summaries are short and unhelpful and missing examples).